# In Delphi 7, how do I escape a percent sign (%) in the Format function?

Tags: delphi, format, escaping, delphi-7

I want to do something like this:

```
SQL.Text := Format('select foo from bar where baz like ''%s%''',[SearchTerm]);
```

But Format doesn't like that last '%', of course. So how can I escape it? `\%`? `%%`?

Or do I have to do this:

```
SQL.Text := Format('select foo from bar where baz like ''%s''',[SearchTerm+'%']);
```

?

Comment: Note that you should better use parameters for your query, or at least  handle quotes within your SearchTerm (e.g. via a QuotedStr() call).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use another % in the format string:

```
SQL.Text := Format('select foo from bar where baz like ''%s%%''',[SearchTerm]);
```

Answer (score 8):

%% , IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

Obligatory:
http://xkcd.com/327/
:-)

Depending on context, your approach might be vulnerable to SQL injection. If the search term comes from user input it would probably be better to use a parameterized query or at least try to sanitize the input.

Comment: True, it would be vulnerable.. but this is for a throwaway POC. I haven't actually figured out how to use parameterized queries with LIKE.

Comment: +1 Parameters will be more secure, and somewhat faster (depending on your DB engine, and if you re-use a prepared statement). You replace the string value by a parameter, and won't touch the LIKE expression. So you can write `SQL.Text := 'select foo from bar where baz like :TERM'` and `ParamByName('TERM').AsText := SearchTerm+'%'`. No more problem with quotes and % chars.

Comment: One of my favourite, +1 for that comic only ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Add 2 percent sign to have 1 single %
Example :

```
 Format('select foo from bar where baz like ''%%%s%%'',[SearchString])
```

Gives you

```
select foo from bar where baz like '%SearchString%'
```